# Javascript: DOM elements updated via jquery.get() aren't responding to extant page listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I'm trying to update the content of a div (`#slide-content`) on clicking certain navigation elements (`h2.pagenav`). The content structure is uniform, and each requested HTML document contains two such nav elements ('Previous','Next'). However, my listener only fires once—for click events on the initial nav button present at page load, and I don't understand why.

My understanding is that when using jQuery's `append()` function instead of `html()`, the appended content should be registered with the DOM and thus available for event listening. Lil' help?

The page structure is pretty simple:

**The HTML**

```
<?php require('common.php'); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Ethogram Lab</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation-icons.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="slide-content">
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row">
                 <!---- content ---->
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-4 small-centered columns">
                    <h2 data-link="slide_0" class="medium button expand text-center pagenav">Start &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fi-play"></i></h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<script src='js/vendor/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='js/foundation.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
<script src='js/app.js'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**The Javascript**
And here is the relevant it of `app.js`

```
/**
 *  PAGE VARS
 */

var DS = '/';
var WEBROOT = "127.0.0.1"+DS+"ethogram"+DS;
var PHP = ".php";

/**
 * DOM LISTENERS
 */
$(".pagenav").click(function() {
    console.log("*** pagenav listener has fired");
    var loc = $(this).attr('data-link');
    var pageNum = loc.substr(-2) == "_" ? loc.substr(-1) : loc.substr(-2);
    var URL = WEBROOT+"slides"+DS+loc+PHP;
    $.get(URL, function(data) {
        $("#slide-content").html('').append(data).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Comment: fyi you can use $(this).data('link') to get your data-link attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ".on()" function should be used.  ".live()" is deprecated.

[.on() function](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$("body").on("click", ".pagenav", function() {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Quite right, tyvm. :) I knew it was small and simple... call it trouble-shooter's block, haha. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
$("body").on ("click",".pagenav",function(){
    // Your code go here
})
```

This function will detect the items created programatically
See [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/)